# angularjs viewmodel binding and update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view model in my angularjs application.

```
function OrderLineViewModel(product, quantity){
    this.name = product.name;
    this.price = product.price;
    this.quantity = quantity;    
    this.total = this.price*this.quantity;
}
```

I want to use this in my controller and update quantity for total.

```
function Ctrl($scope){
    var products = [
        {name: "P1", price: 10.49}, 
        {name: "P2", price: 18.99},
        {name: "P3", price: 14.99}
    ];

    $scope.lines = [];
    $scope.lines.push(new OrderLineViewModel(products[0], 2));
    $scope.lines.push(new OrderLineViewModel(products[1], 3));
    $scope.lines.push(new OrderLineViewModel(products[2], 4));


}
```

my html is like this,

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">    
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in lines">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.quantity"/></td>
                    <td>{{item.total}}</td>
                </tr>                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My quantity is in an html input tag. When I change the input value, total is not updating. Is there a mistake in my code? Here is [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ypyzdjgy/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the total a function to recalculate.

```
function OrderLineViewModel(product, quantity){
    this.name = product.name;
    this.price = product.price;
    this.quantity = quantity;    
    this.getTotal = function() {
        return this.price*this.quantity;
    }
}
```

And in your html update to:

```
<td>{{item.getTotal()}}</td>
```

I usually dont declare a model. I just fetch it from the db. This is how I would solve it:

```
<td>{{item.price*item.quantity}}</td>
```

But it doesn't really work in your case. Unless you return the value to your object.

Comment: should I use function for all calculations in angularjs?

Comment: Depends on the situation.